# symfony: How to fix auto-generated static file path?

Tags: symfony1

I'm trying to create an app with symfony ver.1.4.11.

I created a symbolic link to the path of "web" directory.

```
$ ln -s /path/to/myprojectroot/web/ ~/public_html/subdir/
```

So my frontend app is available like the following URL:

```
http://mydomain.com/subdir/frontend_dev.php
```

And static files are also visible by inputting the following URL directly:

```
http://mydomain.com/subdir/images/someimage.jpg
```

I think this is OK.

But when I call image_tag('someimage.jpg') in template PHP files, the image path will be generated like the following and it will cause 404 Error:

```
http://mydomain.com/images/someimage.jpg
```

The image URLs of default top page are also generated like this:

```
http://mydomain.com/sf/sf_default/images/sfTLogo.png
```

not

```
http://mydomain.com/subdir/sf/sf_default/images/sfTLogo.png
```

Also the URLs by link_to() function cause the same problems.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

You have to tell symfony what is the directory structure.

You can follow [this documentation page](http://www.symfony-project.org/book/1_2/19-Mastering-Symfony-s-Configuration-Files#chapter_19_sub_customizing_the_file_structure).

```
class ProjectConfiguration extends sfProjectConfiguration
{
  public function setup()
  {
    // ...

    $this->setWebDir($this->getRootDir().'/web/subdir');
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I use subdir for the url of my project itself, not only the web dir. So this can not solve my problem although I tried.